# Running a “secure” git server over SSH without gitosis/gitolite?

Tags: git, ssh

Is it possible to run a git server over ssh, using `authorized_keys` and `command=` to restrict access to only the git repositories, without using gitosis/gitolite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, assign the [`git shell`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) as the login shell for all users which shall only have git access.

Comment: Ah, thanks. To make this useful, I had to use the `command="…"` from http://joey.kitenet.net/blog/entry/locking_down_ssh_authorized_keys/, but at least it told me what to look for. Thanks.

Comment: Thans a looooooooooooot :)

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** Not sure about all of the sudden negative rankings; I am obviously not saying to use Gitolite as the OP specifically asked not to use it. I am simply stating that what he is asking for is 95% of what Gitolite's tiny source code does and hence I'm telling him where in it's source he can find the snippet he would want to copy to roll his own.

---

Yes, gitolite does exactly just that. It doesn't swap out the user's shell either.

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="/home/git/.gitolite/src/gl-auth-command jbruce",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAD3NzaC1yc2EABBBCIwAAAQEAtRFmADxUSCX97CS/Uh7/N0y0vL...
```

Notice this doesn't look like a normal `authorized_keys` on the server, it also passes the username as a parameter so that the executed script knows who this ssh key belongs to. The additional benefit of not switching the user's shell (while still keeping it secure) is that if you try to ssh directly into the machine it will not only terminate the session but tell you which repos you have access to before it terminates, if it knows who you are.

Comment: As the title suggests, I'd actually rather avoid using gito*. This is a small project that doesn't need any of the features offered by those tools.

Comment: David, the point is to look at the way gitolite is doing it since it's exactly what you're asking for (authorized_keys and command=). Passing the username to the command= is a cool idea so you can associate the user with more than just an ssh-key. Take the bits you like or just learn from it and do it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this at the beginning of each line in `authorized_keys2`:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="/usr/bin/git-shell -c \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\""
```

That'll allow only git commands over ssh, but will still let you become that user if you need to mess around (from another account):

```
sudo -u git -i
```