# SSH single repo different remotes different git hosts different users/emails/passwords

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I have a single repository. I have two remotes named: Origin and Remote
Origin points to github, Remote points to bitbucket. My github account login uses my personal email  ******@gmail.com, my bitbucket account uses my work email account *******@ca****et.com.

Both Atlassian and github have my ssh keys, my ssh keys are linked and working, they're in different files id_rsa, id_rso.

I want to be able to `git push remote master:development` and separately, not at the same time (don't want sync) `git push origin master:master` etc.

How do I create a git config that allows different user/email for the ssh login?

My git config:

```
[user]
  1 »»»»»»»»email = leaf466@gmail.com
  2 »»»»»»»»name = Serafin Wesnidge
  3 [core]
  4 »»»»»»»»editor = vim
  5 »»»»»»»»pager = diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX
  6 »»»»»»»»excludesfile = /home/user386/.gitignore_global
  7 [push]
  8 »»»»»»»»default = simple
```

(Sorry for formatting, don't know how to get VIM to yank into my ubuntu os buffer. That's a question for another time)

Thanks for the help!

For the Stack Overflow "Duplicate question" police, see below the list of articles I read and the explanation of why they don't apply to my question.

Stack overflow wont let me post my proof so here's an image of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, arrange for your ssh command to send your "GitHub identity" (really: key) to GitHub, and your "Bitbucket identity" to Bitbucket.  That means your *ssh* configuration<sup>1</sup> (not Git configuration!) would include:

```
Host github.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rso
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

(the last line is not required, but is a good idea) and:

```
Host bitbucket.org
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

(assuming I have the ID files correct here).  Then use `ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git` and `ssh://git@bitbucket.com/path/to/repo.git` as the URLs for your two remotes (you can use the `git@$hostingsite:path` syntax if you prefer, this makes no difference, I just like the `ssh://` syntax myself).  The separate remotes will remain separate, and you will only fetch from, or push to, each one as you tell Git to fetch from, or push to, each one.

#### Technical notes

Technically, neither GitHub nor Bitbucket use your email account.  Well, they both use it—but to *send you email*, not to identify some incoming data stream as "you".  They also use it to identify commits "made by you" for display purposes; but such commits can be *injected* by someone else.

In particular, whenever you use SSH to connect to *either* Bitbucket *or* GitHub, you run the non-interactive equivalent of:

```
ssh -T git@$hostingsite
```

where `$hostingsite` is either `bitbucket.org` or `github.com`.  This means you are asking those systems to log in as the user named `git`, not as yourself!  So how do they know that you are *you?*

#### The rest of this discussion is really about how Gitolite works

---

The description below assumes a linear scan through the entire `authorized_keys` file, which is probably far too slow for busy Bitbucket and GitHub servers.  The principles should be the same, though.  The [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) system literally works this way, so as to work on unmodified Unix / Linux servers.

---

The user `git`, on these systems, is not allowed to do very much.  However, that particular user has a very long `authorized_keys` file that has, instead of the usual `ssh-rsa AAAA...` lines, lines that start out with:<sup>2</sup>

```
restrict,command="<path>/gl-auth-command <user>" ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

When the `sshd` server on the machine accepts an incoming key and matches it to the public key stored in user `git`'s `authorized_keys` file, this restricted-and-special-command line makes it run something other than a general-purpose shell.  In this particular example we provide both a path to the Gitolite authorization step, and the *name of the user ssh has just authorized based on this key*.

The request that your Git sent, to run `git upload-pack` or similar, is preserved in an environment variable (`$ORIGINAL_SSH_COMMAND`).  Hence, the actual command just run knows *whose key it was that let you in*, along with what Git operation you asked to do (if you asked to do one—if not, you get that "successfully authorized, but" message that `$hostingsite` prints).

There is additional discussion in [Running a “secure” git server over SSH without gitosis/gitolite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871652/1256452) and in [this superuser.com Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/299927).

---

<sup>1</sup>The ssh configuration file is typically named `$HOME/.ssh/config`.

<sup>2</sup>I use `restrict` here rather than laboriously enumerating all the ssh capabilities to disable.  I think some older sshd versions do not support `restrict`, hence the longer versions in the linked questions.

Comment: Bitbucket lets you push or pull with your own username instead of "git@bitbucket.org", if you want. Also, both GitHub and Bitbucket use each commit's author information to associate that commit with a GH/BB user account.

Comment: @JimRedmond: ah, I don't actually *use* Bitbucket; the examples I have seen (including on their own web site) suggest using `git@bitbucket` in ssh. The point about attributing commits to authors for web-graphs is certainly valid and I should put that in.

Comment: This worked for me. After days of searching finally. Thank you so much!
One thing to note: I've been putting the `Hosts github.com` info into my `.gitconfig` and finally found out I was supposed to put it into a file called "config" inside my `~/.ssh/` directory. All this time...

Really appreciate your explanation. My assumption that my name was required is what was throwing me off, having me ignore one of the "potential duplicate post" posts.

Comment: Aww.. now I'm getting the problem that in Git Kraken (and therefore I'm assuming on my github) I'm not getting credit for my commits (which is important for getting jobs in the future) - How can I resolve this? Or should I simply post this as an entirely new question?

Comment: @Numerials: yes, separate question. GitHub (not sure about Bitbucket) has a fancy method for associating `<user@host>` in commits to "user" though the simplest is just by matching the email address for your GitHub user-name.